# Why scrolling in browser make java applet flicker?

Tags: java, applet

I always found this rather annoying fact about applets, that they disappear if you scroll the browser window, to reappear when the scrolling is over. What's the reason behind this behavior ?

Comment: Note that this question could be a duplicate of this other question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928232/applet-blinking-flashing-under-osx-while-scrolling but there's no answer to that, nor followups

Comment: I've seen similar as well. Mentioned here too: http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=67091&tstart=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Java Applets use the normal/slow 2D capabilities of your graphic card. The fact that the stack is big/complex, OS -> Browser -> Java VM -> Your application does not help either.

Flash applications use 3D acceleration behind the scenes by default, so they do not suffer from this problem since they plug-in into your 3D card directly (bypassing the browser canvas).

You can try running Java2D/applets using 3D acceleration as well, but then you lose the compatibility that Java platform offers (OS agnostic).

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/2d/new_features.html